# location.reload() in onresize function forces users to stay on page

Tags: javascript, safari, reload, onresize

I am having an issue where with the safari browser on mobile when using

```
window.onresize = function () {
  location.reload()
};
```

the user is redirected back to "my" page instead of going to another page.

Any suggestion on what could be done?

Comment: What is 'my page'? `location.reload()` will just reload whatever page that code sits on.

Comment: I am on the page where the code is. (my page), I try to go to a different page like google.com the code above runs and forces the user to stay on (my page)

Comment: Does this happen on Safari only? You may be luckier asking this question on the specific Stack exchange site for users of Apple hardware, software, services, and associated products: [Ask different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: yes seems to be safari mobile only, thank you will try that!